# How do I change the default logon screen in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, unity, login-screen, desktop-background

I'm wondering how I would go about changing the default logon screen (just the background) in Ubuntu 12.04. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The default `lightdm` background is set the same as your desktop background, as long as the background file is under `/usr/share/background` Do you want to set a different background than your desktop?

Comment: its not being set to my desktop background and the desktop background is in /usr/share/background

Answer (score 1):

A solution I found to work is to replace the default background being used by `lightdm`:

```
> sudo cp /path/to/image.png /usr/share/backgrounds
> cd /usr/share/backgrounds
> sudo mv warty-final-ubuntu.png warty-final-ubuntu.png.old
> sudo mv image.png warty-final-ubuntu.png
```

This, however, is just a workaround and probably not the best solution. It is just the most direct way to do it assuming you don't need the default Ubuntu wallpaper.

EDIT: Also make sure that you set your image to have the same owner and permissions as the original *warty-final-ubuntu.png* (root,755),